# Android: Color codes

Tags: android, color-picker, color-codes

I am implementing color picker using the library from AmbilWarna, with alpha being turned on.

Sample code is as follows: https://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/

While a color code is returned,

- bright green with middle transparency: color code = 1980104448
- bright yellow with middle transparency: color code = 1912340224
- bright red with no transparency: color code = -65536 (negative?)
- white with no transparency: color code = -1
- white with 100% transparency: color code = 16777215

### Question:

I would like to use these returned color code to set the background color of the buttons. How could these color codes be interpreted? And why are some being negative? Is it necessary to convert to RGB codes?

Comment: You can directly use these values to set the backgroudn color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All values are in decimal.

`white with 100% transparency: color code = 16777215`

`16777215(10) = FFFFFF(16)`

You need not convert this, you can directly set this.

`myView.setBackgroundColor(value);`

If you have HEX value ex "#FFFFFF", we have to set as

`myView.setBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor ("#FFFFFF"));`

`Color.parseColor ("#FFFFFF");` is called, which inturn returns **`int`**

The below method is copied from `android.graphics.Color.java`

```
/**
 * Parse the color string, and return the corresponding color-int.
 * If the string cannot be parsed, throws an IllegalArgumentException
 * exception. Supported formats are:
 * #RRGGBB
 * #AARRGGBB
 * 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta',
 * 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray', 'grey', 'lightgrey', 'darkgrey',
 * 'aqua', 'fuschia', 'lime', 'maroon', 'navy', 'olive', 'purple',
 * 'silver', 'teal'
 */
public static int parseColor(String colorString) {
    if (colorString.charAt(0) == '#') {
        // Use a long to avoid rollovers on #ffXXXXXX
        long color = Long.parseLong(colorString.substring(1), 16);
        if (colorString.length() == 7) {
            // Set the alpha value
            color |= 0x00000000ff000000;
        } else if (colorString.length() != 9) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color");
        }
        return (int)color;
    } else {
        Integer color = sColorNameMap.get(colorString.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
        if (color != null) {
            return color;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color");
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to convert from decimal to hexadecimal before parsing colors?

Comment: no ,you can use that integers to set background color.

Comment: @pearmak No; the underlying numbers are neither intrinsically decimal or hexadecimal; they're stored in binary, of course. It's just that they're easier to read when described in hexadecimal as each pair of hexadecimal digits—one byte—represents a specific part of the colour. For example, your bright green with mid-transparency is 1980104448. Represented in hex, that's 0x7605FF00 — 0x76 transparent, 0x05 red, 0xFF green, 0x00 blue. We use hex for notation because it's easy to read given the way the colour values are stored. Just by looking you can see it's predominantly green.